# Locating Function Definition Within C#, .NET Project

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking through some C# code (NOTE: I generally work in JavaScript) that was originally done by a 3rd party vendor, and I'm trying to understand some of what I'm coming across.

In the code below you'll notice an `Employee()` function, to which I pass two params. Now, with this function the word "Employee" shows up in green, and I can right click on it to be taken to an `Employee.cs` file, so that's easy enough to trace and figure out what's going on.

However, in the function before that, where a new `GPBaseFactory()` is declared, it's less easy to understand, because that function does not show up in green, and I see no related file in my codebase. In other words, there is no `GPBaseFactory.cs` file. When I try and go to the file with F12 I get a pop-up with the message - "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret".

From what I can tell, `GPBaseFactory()` is also not a Microsoft-defined function that's part of GPDynamics.

Here is the code I just mentioned:

```
 // Save the employee
 var gp = new GPBaseFactory();
    
 var employee = new Employee(employee, gp.Transaction);
 employee.AddEmployeeToTransaction(employee);
```

I do see some `using` reference declarations at the top of this `Program.cs` file, however. Could it be that those are hidden, proprietary files, that contain the `GPBaseFactory()` function definition?

To test this theory, I tried commenting those out (I'm using Visual Studio 2019), but I don't get any warnings or errors in my code, suggesting it can't find something when I do so. So I'm just trying to make sense of this -- again, I regularly in Node/JS, not C# and .NET.

How can I determine what `GPBaseFactory()` refers to, and where the base function definition is located?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Typically press F12 to go to the method definition. F12 on GPBaseFactory should open something at least. I expect it would show only empty methods saying 'from metadata' at the top. This indicates it is from a library that is not part of your code. It really depends on what that library is as to whether you will be able to access the code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm saying I tried that, and all I get is a pop-up wit the message - "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret".

Comment: Then you probably only have the source .cs file open in visual studio rather than the solution/project

Comment: How does one ensure they have the solution/project open then?

Comment: @Banon, look for a `*.sln` file in the root directory of the source code and open that. If you can't find one there or any of the subdirectories then look for a `*.csproj` file and open that.